# Как зациклить таймер

Tags: таймер, циклы, javascript

Здравствуйте! Нужна помощь. Использую таймер обратного отсчета для одностраничника [TimeCircles](http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/index.html). Установил его на сутки. Мне нужно, чтобы он по истечению времени снова автоматически ставился на сутки, а не останавливался. Уже и различные функции из документации пробовал, но все равно не работает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fawf =$("#example").TimeCircles(); 

fawf.addListener(function() {
    if(fawf.getTime() < 1) {
        fawf.restart();
    }
});
```

Плагин неважный какой-то, хоть и красивый.